# Django queryset ordering by _set

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've this models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Image)

class Image(models.Model):
    name = ...
    image = ...
```

If I use `[x.person_set.count() for x in Image.objects.all()]` I get how many people likes every image.

Now I need to order the list. I want something like `Image.objects.all().order_by('person_set.count()')`

I need to get a list of all images ordered by how much people likes it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does everything you want (# of likes, and order by count) in one query.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Image.objects.annotate(Count("person")).order_by("person__count")
```

Comment: thank you dude! Only one question: 'person' is a field of every Image because I declared a ManyToManyField in Image to Person?

Comment: You got it. I originally thought this should be person_set, but after playing around onto own models I figured it out.